# PHP error for an include file on server

Tags: php, include

I've recently moved my site to a new server and I'm getting the following error on the new server.

```
[Thu Jan 17 01:30:09 2013] [error] [client] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'RB/stdlib.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/application.php on line 90
```

I may not have copied a the RB directory but I'm unsure where it is. I've copied the pear folder but still receiving the same error.

Any idea how to resolve this issue and how to get the RB folder with the libs on the new server?

Thanks

Comment: If you have root-access on a unix server you could always try to locate the folder using the `locate` command (as long as it is installed).

Comment: Looks like it's not installed :( but thanks

Comment: Do you know to which library/code the RB folder belongs to? (which PEAR package for example).

Comment: No idea. Just pulling apart previous coder's work.. sorry I can't be of much help.

Comment: Found it :) Thanks anyway